# How to copy just the first worksheet in VBA excel

Tags: excel, ms-office, vba

Hi Im new in VBA I would like to just copy the first sheet in excel using VBA. Here is my code. Im keep getting all the worksheet of all the workbook. What should I do?

```
Sub Consolidator()

    Dim Path            As String
    Dim FileName        As String
    Dim Wkb             As Workbook
    Dim ws              As Worksheet
    Dim diaFolder       As FileDialog

    Set diaFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
          diaFolder.AllowMultiSelect = False
        diaFolder.Show

    fle = diaFolder.SelectedItems(1)


    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
       Path = fle
       FileName = Dir(Path & "\*.xls", vbNormal)

    Do Until FileName = ""
        Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=Path & "\" & FileName)
        For Each ws In Wkb.Worksheets


        ws.Copy Before:=Workbooks(Consolidate)

            ws.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        Next ws

        Wkb.Close False
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Set diaFolder = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
   Do Until FileName = ""
        Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=Path & "\" & FileName)
        For Each ws In Wkb.Worksheets


        ws.Copy Before:=Workbooks(Consolidate)

            ws.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        Next ws

        Wkb.Close False
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop
```

to:

```
       Dim Wb1 as workbook: Set Wb1 = thisworkbook

       Do Until FileName = ""
            Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=Path & "\" & FileName)
            Wkb.sheets(1).Copy After:=Wb1.sheets(Wb1.sheets.count)
            Wkb.Close False
            FileName = Dir()
        Loop
```

Comment: hi thanks for the help but there is an error when I change it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `For Each ws in Wkb.Worksheets...Next ws` will go through every individual worksheet in the workbook's `Worksheets` collection i.e. every worksheet in the workbook will be copied, as you described.

To do just the first worksheet, you need to remove the `For Each...Next` loop, and replace it with:

```
Wkb.Worksheets(1).Copy Before:=Workbooks(Consolidate)
Wkb.Worksheets(1).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
```

In this case `Wkb.Worksheets(1)` returns the first worksheet in the current workbook `Wkb`